# How can I check multiple conditions inside of UseMemo()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my React component, I pass in a prop called `chemicalSignature`. I also have a value that I get from localStorage.

I have a constant called `reactionValue` that I want to either hold the value of `chemicalSignature` or the value of `chemicalVaultValue`.

I want `reactionValue` to use the value of `chemicalVaultValue` if `chemicalSignature` is null or `chemicalVaultValue` has a value.

If `chemicalVaultValue` is null, then I want it to use `chemicalSignature`.

If both `chemicalVaultValue` and `chemicalSignature` are null, I want it to use a place holder value like, "...Your Chemical String".

Right now, I set the value of `reactionValue` using `useMemo()` as you can see below.

Is there a way to check 3 conditions using `useMemo()`?

The 3 conditions would be:

```
// if chemicalVaultValue has value and chemicalSignature is null:
if(chemicalVaultValue && !chemicalSignature) {
    reactionValue = chemicalVaultValue;
}

// if chemicalVaultValue has a value (we don't care about chemicalSignature at this point)
if(chemicalVaultValue) {
    reactionValue = chemicalVaultValue;
}

// if both are null, use a placerholder text value
if(!chemicalVaultValue && !chemicalSignature) {
    reactionValue = "...Your Chemical String";
}
```

I can't figure out how to use this in useMemo().

So far I just have this:

```
const App = ({ chemicalId, chemicalSignature, chemical }) => {

    var chemicalVaultValue = localStorage.getItem(chemicalId);

    const reactionValue = useMemo(() => {
        return chemicalVaultValue || chemicalSignature;
    }, [chemicalId, chemicalSignature]
    );

    const [chemicalState, setChemicalState] = useState(reactionValue);
```

Would there be a way to check all 3 conditions inside useMemo()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first 2 conditions could be merged only in one condition, since `chemicalSignature` doesn't have a role in it:

```
const reactionValue = useMemo(() => {
    if(chemicalVaultValue) return chemicalVaultValue;
    if(!chemicalVaultValue && !chemicalSignature) return "...Your Chemical String";
}, [chemicalVaultValue, chemicalSignature]
);
```

fwiw there is another condition `!chemicalVaultValue && chemicalSignature` that is not covered. If it should return the placeholder as well you function could be reduced to a ternary operator:

```
const reactionValue = useMemo(() => {
    return chemicalVaultValue ? chemicalVaultValue : "...Your Chemical String";
}, [chemicalVaultValue]
);
```

Comment: Thanks! So would the 2nd option cover all possible conditions?

Comment: yes it would, given `chemicalSignature` seems to be not relevant on decide between a placeholder or `chemicalVaultValue`. also I fixed the dependency, it should be `chemicalVaultValue` instead of `chemicalId` at your memo.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way with nullish coascaling. You might be able to just use `||`, but [this eslint rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/52b60852d0ba6bb6abe519c9d3ec1b231793e91d/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/prefer-nullish-coalescing.md#enforce-the-usage-of-the-nullish-coalescing-operator-instead-of-logical-chaining-prefer-nullish-coalescing) Explains why it's better to use `??`.

```js
const reactionValue = useMemo(
  () => chemicalVaultValue ?? chemicalSignature ?? '...Your Chemical Strin', 
  [chemicalId, chemicalSignature]
);
```